# App not running in the background

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios11, swift4

In my background mode enabled blue tooth app when app enters the background. After sometime didfinishlaunching is called and app starts again. But some times the saved info in key-chain is not found and app starts from the very beginning not from the from the screen if info in the key-chain was present. Below are the logs in different circumstances:
1. When key-chain info is not found
   **New Line**  Time: 2018-02-03 17:15:50 +0000, applicationDidEnterBackground -----

**New Line**  Time: 2018-02-03 17:15:50 +0000, stop tracking in background

**New Line**  Time: 2018-02-03 17:30:07 +0000, didfinishlaunching

**New Line**  Time: 2018-02-03 17:30:07 +0000, start is added as no auth is available

**New Line**  Time: 2018-02-03 17:30:08 +0000, Start View did load

2.When key-chain info is found
**New Line**  Time: 2018-02-02 12:37:39 +0000, applicationDidEnterBackground -----

**New Line**  Time: 2018-02-02 12:37:39 +0000, stop tracking in background

**New Line**  Time: 2018-02-02 12:45:50 +0000, didfinishlaunching

**New Line**  Time: 2018-02-02 12:45:51 +0000, home is added as auth is available

But my main concern why didfinidhlaunching is called at all?

Comment: Your app can be terminated at any time when it is suspended. It will be relaunched if you have opted in to Core Bluetooth state restoration and a Bluetooth event occurs. However, there is a good chance the device is locked at this point so you need to make sure that your keychain item is available when the device is locked.

Comment: How to make sure keychain item is available ?

Comment: Set the keychain items [`access`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/ksecattraccessible)to "after first unlock"

Comment: "afterFirstUnlock" or "always"? What's the difference between these two?

Comment: Always is always available while after first unlock is only available after the first time the user unlocks the device after it restarts

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. But my main issue is app should not be killed in background. Also I think my app is not using much memory. It's just around 20 mb. I have also an old version of this project which is with swift 2 and xcode 7. If I use that project app is not terminated in the background. I have actually based my app on that project it self.